# Creating a deep copy of a doubly-linked list node

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, deep-copy

I have my node defined something like:

```
class LLNode
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<LLNode> prev;
    std::shared_ptr<LLNode> next;
    std::shared_ptr<int> data;
    LLNode(void)
    : prev(std::shared_ptr<LLNode>(nullptr)),
    next(std::shared_ptr<LLNode>(nullptr)),
    data(std::shared_ptr<int>(nullptr))
    {
    }

    LLNode(const LLNode &node)
    : prev(std::shared_ptr<LLNode>(node.prev == nullptr?nullptr:new LLNode(node.prev))),
    next(std::shared_ptr<LLNode>(node.next == nullptr?nullptr:new LLNode(node.next))),
    data(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(node.data)))
    {
    }
};
```

However, if I have a node which is linked to another node (which obviously will often be the case), copying node A will instantiate a copy of the next node B, which in turn will try to instantiate a copy of node A, which will try to copy node B, etc. etc. until there's a stackoverflow or memory error. This could be fixed by only instantiating a new copy of next (or prev), but then nothing linked previously (or next) to this node will be copied.

Is there a good way to copy a doubly linked list node?

Comment: I'm confused why you're using `shared_ptr` if you're going to completely subvert its entire purpose anyway.

Comment: Your problem stems from indiscriminate use of shared_ptr where one would otherwise use a pointer.  Use shared_ptr only when you want multiple instances of the pointer to share ownership of the referenced object.

Comment: I want to be able to use the shared_ptr when one only wants to reference to the next/prev node, but when a deep copy of the node is required, it needs to create a shared_ptr to a new copied object, otherwise I'd only have a shallow copy. The answer was provided below, though (use an external copy method)

Comment: Objects that hold each other's pointers in a `shared_ptr` is going to almost **ensure** memory leaks.  This is know as a cyclic reference.

Comment: You can break the shared_ptr cycle by using weak_ptr for either next or prev.  My personal preference would be prev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the mistake that you are trying to copy the whole chain/list from a single node. That does not make that much sense to do in copy ctor of a list node. Make the copy ctor just copy the members' values, do not recurse. Copying the whole chain/list is the job for a `LinkedList` class.

Comment: +1 for "is the job of a `LinkedList` class. Copying a single node may be useful in some algorithms, but usually you don't even want to manage single nodes out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Just set next and prev to null, regardless of the next and prev values of the node being copied.  Write a separate function that copies the node and all it's children, which would be used to copy the whole list.